# How to Play or convert a QCP file to MP3

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3

Exactly as the title says. My friend sent me a file which turns out to be a QCP file and I have been downloading all kinda of programs people told me to download and I have come up with nothing to convert this thing into an MP3 to listen to it.

What program should I use to listen to QCP file?

Comment: Have you tried *Sound Converter*?

Comment: I don't believe that `Sound Converter` can convert `.QCP` files.

Comment: VLC does play this format. Or you can try using [FFMEG as here](http://superuser.com/questions/236117/qcp-mp3-on-a-mac) .

Comment: Do you try http://superuser.com/questions/236117/qcp-mp3-on-a-mac? It's BASH, you just need ffmpeg and all will work great. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Converting audio formats with FFMPEG

**First make sure that FFMPEG is installed by either**

1. [Installing via the Software centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libav-tools/)
2. Typing `sudo apt-get install libav-tools` into Terminal

**Converting the file:**

1. Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Navigate to the folder your source file is found in by typing `cd` followed by the folder you want to enter.  You start in ~ (Your home folder)
3. Type in `ffmpeg -i sourcefile.qcp targetfile.mp3`

Comment: `ffmpeg` is currently a "dead" project which is renamed to `avconv`.

Comment: I got messages saying to use FFMPEG so I put another answer on in case it helps.

Comment: @Adobe ffmpeg isn't dead. It's an active project, it's just somebody at Ubuntu decided to switch to avconv instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/399105

Comment: @bmaupin: you right -- I didn't know it back then, but now I know: http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html

Answer (score 2):

### Converting an audio file with VLC

First you will need 
[VLC Media Player](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/).  I have provided a link to the Software Centre for that.

**NOTE: If you just want to play the file, instead just open it with VLC and ignore the following instructions.**

1. Open up VLC
2. Open the "Media" menu
3. Choose "Convert/Save" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
4. Make sure you are on the "File" tab
5. Using the add button, choose the files you would like to convert
6. Click the "Convert/Save" button
7. Click the "Browse" button and choose where you would like to save the converted file
8. Under "Profile" choose what you would like the format of your converted file to be.  *Make sure you choose one of the "Audio -" options*
9. Click the "Start" button
10. **VLC will look like it's playing the file without sound and will say "Streaming", but leave it alone until it has finished "playing the file."**

Now the file should be converted to whatever format you selected as whatever file you selected to save as.

Comment: its like having a seisure then freezing... :( i even switched it to flac bc that sound converter will change the flac to an mp3... but nadda...

Comment: thought it was working... im getting upset... i want to listen to my girls recoding she sent me...

Comment: its like spazing out saying its streaming then it goes grey after like 30 seconds...

Comment: Do you have Audacity?

Comment: no i dont have audocity... yet

Comment: audacity i mean...

Comment: nope it wont play it at all... what converter would convert to ogg?

Comment: I was thinking that instead of converting to MP3 with VLC you could to it do an OGG instead.  But if the file won't play in VLC it likely won't convert with it, so I am stumped on that one.

Comment: this is all its doing:

Comment: http://i42.photobucket.com/albums/e302/korn_23_2004/Screenshotfrom2012-08-03025046.png

Comment: yup i did just that and you see what its doing